# Ошибка при работе с postgresql + docker

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Проблема состоит в следующем

Сервер запускается работает но как только, делаю запросы в базу, выдает такую ошибку

```
error infra/server/handler.js ::ffff:127.0.0.1 called redemption.list and it failed (async) due to Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres postgres:5432
at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

Код контролера

```
    const pg = require ('../../infra/pg')
module.exports = {
    list
}
function list(){
    return pg.select('*').from('orders')
}
```

Comment: По всей видимости, не нашёл он сервер постгреса. Вы его прилинковали?

Comment: Что именно вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Я о том, что он не смог понять, к чему обращаться по хостнейму `postgres`, который у вас в URL. Вы что-нибудь сделали, чтобы под этим именем был нужный вам контейнер?

Comment: нет, не сделал. Как это исправить?

Comment: Может, и сделали, просто не знаете. Файлик для Docker Compose предоставить можете? Достаточно определения сервисов постгреса и его потребителя.

Comment: Да не мне. В вопрос.

Comment: проще всего (но не очень верно) определить контейнер как виртуальную машину. ну так вот, у вас node.js и postgresql выполняются на разных машинах, поэтому по адресу 127.0.0.1, по которому пытается подключиться ваш код, не висит сокета постгре.

Comment: если вопрос еще актуален, то не могли бы вы добавить docker-compose.yml в вопрос?